# How to add CSS transition to a product item only for transforming image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a product card like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="card border-0 position-relative">
      <div class="innerAnimation">
          <img src="/storage/item1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="">  
      </div>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I wanted to add some *card image zoom in* on hovering over images of this card.

So I added this:

```
.innerAnimation img{
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
.innerAnimation:hover img{
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

But now the problem is, the image move outside of it's box while the zoom in effect should affect the image inside the box.

Here is result of zoom-in effect on hovering over images:

[image]

And this is expected result example:

**With No Effect:**

[image]

**Zoom-in effect Applies:**

[image]

So how to do this with CSS?

Comment: You should be changing the size of the image instead of scaling it.

Comment: @MrSandyWilly Can you tell me an example plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `overflow: hidden` for `innerAnimation` class

```css
.innerAnimation {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.innerAnimation img {
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.innerAnimation:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card border-0 position-relative d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="innerAnimation">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/cinqueterre.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="innerAnimation">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/cinqueterre.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="innerAnimation">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/cinqueterre.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure the size of your innerAnimation div matches the size of your image and the apply overflow hidden

```
.innerAnimation{
  width: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with a border to help illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/yhqja5Lw/